# Jquery execute mouse click after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a [blog category page](http://samuraicoder.in/blog) to which I want to re direct from my one of my blog posts page and I want to simulate mouse click events which tells which category do they belong to i.e mouse click on the appropriate category in the blog page.I have achieved this on the blog page itself by means of jquery as follows,

```
function categoryNav(){
    window.onload() = function(){
    $('#item-0').click();
    $('#item-0-0').click();  
    };
 }
```

This works fine standalone on the page, but somehow I am not able to combine this with a href linking from my posts page i.e after a link click from the page this function is executed, in that case where the click always gets executed first before the redirect.

I have tried window.onload,document.onload,document.ready but nothing seems to work correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you clicking the link to show that it is _active_ link?

Comment: Nope..there is a link which is on a separate page.On clicking it 1)I want it to redirect to the blog page 2)Simulate the mouse actions as above on the same page.The problem is mouse actions works separately, but does not work after step 1 i.e mouse clicks gets executed first.

Comment: are you sure you are using window.onload correctly?? can you show that code too ??

Comment: Can you use a query string on the href and then trigger a click on the target page based on the query?  Or have I misunderstood what you're doing?

Comment: @sideroxylon : Yes you have understood my intent correctly,but can you give me an example on how to use it,sorry I am kind of new to javascript.

Comment: @Madusudanan you have an error in blog page , have you considered that ?

Comment: @nithin : Yeah, that seems to be there for some time due to the side nav bar, but that does not seems to affect other stuff on the page, or I should I be fixing that?

Comment: @Madusudanan remember js will stop executing if it encounters an error. well to be precise, async js wont. so i guss you added this code after the line which shows error hence it was not executed

Comment: @Madusudanan is it working ?? as for testing, try removing the erroneous code and running this function

Comment: @nithin : The error did not create any problem, sideroxylon solution worked for me.But, I would definitely consider your advise.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first click, generate a url in the form `www.myblog.com/?item-0`.  Then, on the target page (on DOM ready):

```
s = location.search;
        if(s != '') {
            var split = s.split('?');
            var cat = split[1];
            $('#' + cat + '').click();
        }
```

In the case above, you should trigger a click on `#item-0`.